# Google App Engine - Memcache expiration

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, memcached

I am using Google App Engine for my application and for reducing the datastore costs i am extensively using memcache.

Example of a snippet given below,

```
val = memcache.get('forum')
if val is None:
      val = 'stackoverflow'
      memcache.add('forum', val, time=600)

return val
```

The time expiration I have set is for 10 mins (600/60 = 10 mins), and the value is not in cache after 10 mins, but in app engine memcache document its says the values will not be evicted as below ( as time is only an optional parameter)

> add(key, value, time=0, min_compress_len=0, namespace=None)source Sets
>   a key's value, iff item is not already in memcache.
>
> Parameters 
>   key -- Key to set. See docs on Client for details.
>
> value -- Value to set. Any type. If complex, will be pickled.
>
> time -- Optional
>   expiration time, either relative number of seconds from current time
>   (up to 1 month), or an absolute Unix epoch time. By default, items
>   never expire, though items may be evicted due to memory pressure.
>   Float values will be rounded up to the nearest whole second.
>   min_compress_len -- Ignored option for compatibility. namespace -- a
>   string specifying an optional namespace to use in the request. Returns
>   True if added. False on error.

I am also using a Dedicated memcache, it says the items will never expire, but in my case the items expires when I set the time (for eg: time=600s), why it is so ??

Comment: The doc text you included says the default is to never expire, however you are supplying a time, so it will.  In other words because you supply time parameter you are overriding the default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I thought its an optional parameter - and eventhough we specify it - items will expire only due to memory pressure. Are you sure, if we specify time - items will expiry after that time. As my google app engine costs is quite high - I am finding a way to optimize it, moving all the data to memcache for higher expiration time of 1 day and can I know whether its good idea to do so??

Comment: You said in your initial question:  " but in my case the items expires when I set the time (for eg: time=600s), why it is so ??"  From your initial description it is working as documented.  Excluding that option will mean it never expires.

Answer (score 1):

From [How cached data expires](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#how_cached_data_expires) (emphasis mine):

> The app can provide an expiration time when a value is stored, as
>   either a number of seconds relative to when the value is added, or as
>   an absolute Unix epoch time in the future (a number of seconds from
>   midnight January 1, 1970). **The value is evicted no later than this
>   time**, though it can be evicted earlier for other reasons.

Comment: Yes, I read about it and if we provide a expiration time - the value will be evicted on completion of the time, s my google app engine costs is quite high - I am finding a way to optimize it, moving all the data to memcache for higher expiration time of 1 day and can I know whether its good idea to do so??

Comment: Your DB costs would go down, but your memcache costs will go up. $1.44/GB/day (equivalent to 2.4M entity reads) May be worthy (or not) depending on your data structure and its usage pattern (cache hit rate, item size, etc). In my case I preferred regular memcache (free) but only selected (highly used) data cached, with no expiry time (if appropriate).